# Appending to list doesn't seem to stay outside for loop

Tags: python, arrays, json

I'm trying to append a dictionary to a list.

```py
try:
  with open('data.json', 'r+') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    x = 0
    output = []
    for word in lines:
      new_data = {
        **data,
        'question': lines[x],
        'answer': lines[x+1]
      }
      output.append(new_data)
      x += 1
    print(output)
    # json.dump(output, file, indent=2, sort_keys=True)
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

There is no output. My goal is to dump the entire list of dictionaries into a JSON file after processing. Is there any way to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: The last iteration of the loop will try to access beyond the end of the `lines` list.

Comment: If you're not getting an error from that, it means `lines` is empty. That's why you get empty output.

Comment: If you're getting that error, the `except` skips over the `print(output)` line.

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: What is the value of ``lines``?

Comment: The way you're using `lines[x]` and `lines[x+1]` makes no sense. On the first iteration it does `question: line[0], answer: line[1]`. The next iteration does `question: line[1], answer: line[2]`. How can line 1 be both an answer and a question?

Comment: What you probably want is `for x in range(0, len(lines), 2):`

Comment: Don't use `except Exception` like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last iteration of the `for` loop is going to get an error because `lines[x+1]` will be outside the valid indexes. The `try/except` will catch this error and skip over `print(output)`, so you get no output.

It seems like you want to process the `lines` list in pairs, not one line at a time. Use `range(0, len(lines), x)` to iterate through the indexes 2 at a time.

```
with open('data.json', 'r+') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
output = [{**data, "question": lines[x], "answer": lines[x+1]} for x in range(0, len(lines), 2)]
```

Comment: This code still gave me an error. I added this instead: `output = [{**data, "question": lines[x], "answer": lines[x+1]} for x in range(0, len(lines) - 1, 2)]` Thanks for the help btw :D

Comment: That shouldn't be needed if `lines` has an even number of elements.